# Downloading different files when cloning and pulling

Tags: git, github

i tried to play with github's forking, so i forked AndEngine project.
Now when i do:

```
git clone https://github.com/Apoptyzm/AndEngine.git 
git pull origin master
```

I get tons of auto-merged conflicts and conflicts like:

> CONFLICT: FontFactory.java deleted in HEAD and modified in {HASH}.
>   Version {HASH} of FontFactory.java left in tree.

So my question is why am i downloading different files from my repo on default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HEAD branch of the original repo is `GLES2`, meaning that it's the one checked out after the clone. It must be quite different from `master` branch, that's why you get conflicts when pulling from it.

Pull on `GLES2` instead and you should be fine, or checkout `master`, depends on what branch you want to code with.